# Asynctask: pass two or more values from doInBackground to onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an Asynctask which retrieves two int vaules and i want to pass them to onPostExecute to show them on the view.
Here is my code:

```
    public class QueryServer extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Integer> { 

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... serverAddress) {
        Log.d("QueryServer", ""+serverAddress[0]);
        MCQuery mcQuery = new MCQuery("" + serverAddress[0] ,25565);
        QueryResponse response = mcQuery.basicStat();

        int Onlineplayers = response.getOnlinePlayers(); //first vaule
        int Maxplayers = response.getMaxPlayers();  //second vaule

        Log.d("MCQuery", "" + Onlineplayers + " OnlinePlayers");
        return Onlineplayers;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer Onlineplayers){

        TextView onlinePlayersView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.online_players);

        onlinePlayersView.setText(""+Onlineplayers+"/"+ Maxplayers); //i need to pass Maxplayers to use it here


    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can define a Wrapper class that holds two integers:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public int onlinePlayers;
    public int maxPlayers;
}
```

and use it in place of `Integer`:

```
public class QueryServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Wrapper> { 

    protected Wrapper doInBackground(String... serverAddress) {
        Log.d("QueryServer", ""+serverAddress[0]);
        MCQuery mcQuery = new MCQuery("" + serverAddress[0] ,25565);
        QueryResponse response = mcQuery.basicStat();

        int onlinePlayers = response.getOnlinePlayers(); //first vaule
        int maxPlayers = response.getMaxPlayers();  //second vaule

        Log.d("MCQuery", "" + onlinePlayers + " onlinePlayers");
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.onlinePlayers = onlinePlayers;
        w.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
        return w;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Wrapper w){

        TextView onlinePlayersView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.online_players);

        onlinePlayersView.setText(""+w.onlinePlayers+"/"+ w.maxPlayers); //i need to pass Maxplayers to use it here


    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public class QueryServer extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Integer>{...}
```

Replace the `Integer` generic param to `ArrayList<Integer>` or to `Integer[]`

This way your `doInBackground()` will look like this:

```
protected Integer[] doInBackground(String... serverAddress) 
{
    ...do what you need to do...
    //Then create an array, fill with data, and return.
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        arr[i] = i; //just an example
    return arr;
}
```

And the in your `onPostExecute()`

```
protected void onPostExecute(Integer [] Onlineplayers)
{
    //Do whatever you want with your array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is simply declare a small container object with the fields you want to return, then return an instance of that from doInBackground:

```
private class QueryResult {
    int onlinePlayers;
    int maxPlayers;

    public QueryResult( int onlinePlayers, int maxPlayers ) {
        this.onlinePlayers = onlinePlayers;
        this.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
    }
}

protected QueryResult doInBackground(String... serverAddress) {
    // ...

    return new QueryResult( onlinePlayers, maxPlayers );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making those two ints members of `QueryServer`?

`onPostExecute()` doesn't run until after `doInBackground()` is finished, so there shouldn't be any threading issues.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, replace `Integer` with `ArrayList of Objects`. with this array, you can pass any collection of any types. but obviously, the downside is you should cast the members and you should know all the types...