# Using AsyncTask to get data in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Trying to set text in EditText from AsyncTask in my fragment.  This works great in my other classes but the Fragment is throwing me off.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment_main, container,
            false);

        new getinfo().execute();

        if (emailTwo != null) {
            email2.setText(emailTwo);
        } 
        if (emailThree != null) {
            email3.setText(emailThree);
        }
        if (mailingaddress1 != null) {
            mail1.setText(mailingaddress1);
        }
} // end of onCreate

class getinfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // onPreExecute() and onPostExecute here

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        int success;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", restoredemail));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 2) {
                emailTwo = json.getString("secondemail");
                emailThree = json.getString("thirdemail");
                mailingaddress1 = json.getString("mailingaddress1");
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I tried putting the editText .setText in the onPostExecute but the fragment won't allow it. I also tried returning the values but it only allows one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

- Create an interface in your async task with a method.
- Implement that interface in your activity. Override the method
- Now inside your onPostExecute, call the interface method to notify the activity
- From within that method (in your activity), just notify your fragment by calling its method which should simply set the text in the EditText field.

**Example Code**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements MyAsyncTask.OnDataFetchedListener
{
   //do all your stuff here
   private EditText text;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView( ....)
   {
       //get edit text views here
   }

   @Override
   public void updatText(String[] data)
   { 
     String firstValue = data[0];
     text.setText(firstValue);
   } 
}
```

Now in your async task do the following:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsnycTask<String, String, String> 
{
    private String[] data;

    @Override onPreExecute(){}

    @Override protected String doInBackground(String ..)
    {
        //do whatever you need here and return whatever you need
        //add your data to the list here
    }


    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
       //you can return a list of results here
       try{
           ((OnDataFetchedListener), getActivity()).updateText(data);
       }catch(ClassCastException)
       {
       }
    }

   public interface OnDataFetchedListener
  {
      void updateText(String[] data);l
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I wasn't ever able to implement the new class. Eclipse always wanted to create a new class with that name. I am sure it is my error! I was able to populate my EditText and TextViews in the Fragment with the help of this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833978/asynctask-pass-two-or-more-values-from-doinbackground-to-onpostexecute    By adding a wrapper class and putting it as an argument in the asynctask create I was able to return it's values in OnPostExecute and set the values.  Thanks for all of your help and I still believe your answer is the correct way to do this.